# What is a good explanation of how to read the histogram feature of TensorBoard?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, tensorflow

Question is simple, **how do you read those graphs**? I read their explanation and it doesn't make sense to me.

I was reading TensorFlow's [newly updated readme file for TensorBoard](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.9/tensorflow/tensorboard/README.md) and in it it tries to explain what a "histogram" is. First it clarifies that its not really a histogram:

> Right now, its name is a bit of a misnomer, as it doesn't show
>   histograms; instead, it shows some high-level statistics on a
>   distribution.

I am trying to figure out what their description is actually trying to say.

Right now I am trying to parse the specific sentence:

> Each line on the chart represents a percentile in the distribution
>   over the data: for example, the bottom line shows how the minimum
>   value has changed over time, and the line in the middle shows how the
>   median has changed.

The first question I have is, what do they mean by "each line". There are horizontal axis and there are lines that make a square grid on the graph or maybe the plotted lines, themselves. Consider a screen shot from [the TensorBoard example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/index.html#events):

[image]

What are they referring to with "lines"? In the above example what are the lines and percentiles that they are talking about?

Then the readme file tries to provide more detail with an example:

> Reading from top to bottom, the lines have the following meaning:
>   [maximum, 93%, 84%, 69%, 50%, 31%, 16%, 7%, minimum]

However, its unclear to me what they are talking about. What is lines and what percentiles?

It seems that they are trying to replace this in the future, but meanwhile, I am stuck with this. Can someone help me understand how to use this?

Comment: my question is not unclear. Its easy, how do you read those graphs created by the TensorFlow library.

Comment: just found: https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/IDymIAT5KDA might be useful

Comment: might be helpful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220491/how-does-one-interpret-histograms-given-by-tensorflow-in-tensorboard/221971#221971

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The lines that they are talking about are described below:
[image]

as for the meaning of percentile, check out the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile),
basically, the 93rd percentile means that 93% of the values are situated below the 93rd percentile line

Comment: I'm still confused on how to read this. so that that mean that 0.160 was the largest value and it happened with 1.00k frequency? I'm confused how to use both the x and y axis together to give meaning to these plots. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It means at between the 0.0 and the 1000k step (I'm not sure what the x-axis is, I dont use TensorFlow), the values started at 0.1 and then the range of the values increased from 0.160 (the maximum) to ~0.060 (the minimum). However, the median (half the values of are above and half are below the median values), did not really change over the 1000k steps.

Comment: I think I know how to read it now, does it mean that at the 1000k step, 93% of the values where ~0.130? So for a specific time step, say x, the value y on some curve f_i = f_i(x) means that at step x there where i% of the values where value y. That makes more sense to me. I guess the max and min just show the range at each time step and show no correspondence with percentages/percentiles.

Comment: No, it does not mean that 93% of the values were equal to 0.130, it means that 93% of the values were _below_ 0.130

Comment: darn, yea, sorry got confused on the definition of percentiles. But yea, thats what I meant to say. It indicates the cumulative frequency count according to the rule I mentioned above. Thanks for the correction!